# Really stuck serving django project with gunicorn

Tags: ubuntu, django

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 trying to serve a django2 weblog.

I keep getting an error of an old syntax mistake('Unitt'), that I have corrected and saved. It may have to do with file permissions. On digital ocean I'm told "The project files are owned by the root user instead of a sudo user". That's a bit confusing because I have sudo setup for my django user and I go through that to change things. When I use ls -l on my django folders Im working on they are shown to owned by django. I am assuming thats enough proof

I used visudo to pull this up and add django

```
#Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

#Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

django  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Here is my `gunicorn.service` file where the system says I have Unitt instead of Unit like I have. Could this actully be a problem of the root account owning this. Is it safe to have django own this.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=django
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/django_project/
ExecStart=/home/django/django_project/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/django/django_project.sock django_project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Lastly I have my project set up like this

```
/home/django/django_project/django_project/(database, manage.py)
```